# SetNamedSecurityInfo() function returning ACCESS_IS_DENIED (error code 5 in Winerror.h) even when the application is run as admin

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, service

I have an application in which it is preferable to set the services installed by it to not be editable and interruptable by the user (as seen in the screenshot of one of the installed service below) and I have implemented a variant of the following logic to accomplish this:

1. Read the security descriptor of the Windows service that does not allow the user to edit it and terminate it in any way (as seen in the screenshot below in which the service properties of the concerned service does not allow the user to even terminate it, ensuring that it runs perpetually and is only terminated when and if it is finally removed).
2. Set the previously read security descriptor to the service installed by the application to exhibit the same features.

Here's the real problem: the code returns an error value of 5 as the value returned by the `SetNamedSecurityInfo()`, which corresponds to `ACCESS_IS_DENIED` as per `Winerror.h`, even when the concerned binary is run as administrator. Lastly, the part where I got even more lost is when I tried using service names of other installed services or used a custom string security descriptor (when calling the `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor()` function), I didn't get any error as the code operated as required. On even further investigations, I have found that this error is only reproducible on using the names of the service that implement the required behavior: not allowing the end-user to edit the startup type and also the service status of the service.

Code used to perform the said task:

```
// Fetch the security descriptor for "WdNisSvc" (Service name that corresponds to the display name of "Windows Security Service")
LPCWSTR serviceNameToGetSecurityInformationFrom = L"WdNisSvc";
SC_HANDLE serviceManagerHandle = NULL, serviceHandle = NULL;
char securityDescriptorBuffer[1024];
DWORD lengthOfReturnedValue = 0;
LPWSTR stringBuffer = NULL;
unsigned long lengthOfString = 0;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR securityDescriptor = { 0 };
LPSTR daclBuffer = nullptr, ownerSidBuffer = nullptr, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer = nullptr;
DWORD daclBufferSize = NULL, ownerSidBufferSize = NULL, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize = NULL, saclBufferSize = NULL, primaryGroupSidBufferSize = NULL;
WCHAR serviceName[] = L"test_service";
DWORD securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue = NULL;
BOOL securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue = NULL;
serviceManagerHandle = OpenSCManager(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
if (serviceManagerHandle == nullptr) {
    cout << "Error opening Service Manager Handle (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
}
else {
    serviceHandle = OpenService(serviceManagerHandle, serviceNameToGetSecurityInformationFrom, READ_CONTROL); //| WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC
    if (serviceHandle == nullptr) {
        cout << "Error opening service (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
    }
    else {
        if (!QueryServiceObjectSecurity(serviceHandle, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, securityDescriptorBuffer, sizeof(securityDescriptorBuffer), &lengthOfReturnedValue)) {
            cout << "Error obtaining service's security information (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
        }
        else {
            if (!ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(securityDescriptorBuffer, SDDL_REVISION_1, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &stringBuffer, &lengthOfString)) {
                cout << "Error getting string value corresponding to the security information (" << GetLastError() << ")";
            }
            else {

                if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(stringBuffer, SDDL_REVISION_1, &securityDescriptor, NULL)) {
                    cout << "Conversion of string descriptor to security descriptor failed with error " << GetLastError() << ".\n";
                } 
                else {
                    absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer = new CHAR[0];
                    ownerSidBuffer = new CHAR[0];
                    daclBuffer = new CHAR[0];
                    securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue = MakeAbsoluteSD(securityDescriptor, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer, &absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize, (PACL)daclBuffer, &daclBufferSize, NULL, &saclBufferSize, ownerSidBuffer, &ownerSidBufferSize, NULL, &primaryGroupSidBufferSize);
                    if ((!securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue) && (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) == GetLastError()) {
                        // Induced error
                        //cout << "ERROR: Inadequate size of the buffers implemented.\n";
                        delete[] absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer;
                        delete[] ownerSidBuffer;
                        delete[] daclBuffer;
                        absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer = new CHAR[absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize];
                        ownerSidBuffer = new CHAR[ownerSidBufferSize];
                        daclBuffer = new CHAR[daclBufferSize];
                        securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue = MakeAbsoluteSD(securityDescriptor, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer, &absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize, (PACL)daclBuffer, &daclBufferSize, NULL, &saclBufferSize, ownerSidBuffer, &ownerSidBufferSize, NULL, &primaryGroupSidBufferSize);
                    }
                    securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue = SetNamedSecurityInfo(serviceName, SE_SERVICE, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, ownerSidBuffer, NULL, (ACL*)daclBuffer, NULL);
                    if (securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                        cout << "Error setting security info (" << securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue << ").\n";
                    }
                    delete[] absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer;
                    delete[] ownerSidBuffer;
                    delete[] daclBuffer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot of one of the installed Windows service that exhibits the required behavior:
[image: Screenshot of the properties box of "Windows Security Service"]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just try setting the DACL and not the owner does it work? There are a number of conditions placed on setting the owner as detailed in the docs for `SetNamedSecurityInfo` and you may not be fulfilling all of them.

Comment: at first yes, problem in `OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION` - you need have `SeRestorePrivilege` for set **not self** *SID* as the owner of object. than your code too complex - for what all this manipulations ? you need take SD from `QueryServiceObjectSecurity` and pass it as is to `SetServiceObjectSecurity`

Comment: @JonathanPotter I have removed all instances of ```OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION``` and omitted the use of ```ownerSidBuffer```, but it still doesn't operate as expected; the function ```SetNamedSecurityInfo()``` now returns an error regarding invalid parameters.

Comment: @hecate - your code pointless complex. for what all this transormations of SD ?

Comment: @RbMm Please disregard my last comment, it was due to a silly error on my part on the arguments passed to the ```SetServiceObjectSecurity()```!

Comment: @RbMm Actually, the code runs without any errors now, after I have removed the ```OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION``` from the ```SetServiceObjectSecurity()``` function but it does not "lock" the service status in the properties page.

Comment: `ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor`, `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor`, `MakeAbsoluteSD` - for what all this ?

Comment: @RbMm It is to comply with the arguments that need to be passed to the ```SetServiceObjectSecurity()``` function, especially to get values for the ```daclBuffer``` and ```ownerSidBuffer```.

Comment: no, your code much more complex than need. i give you solution yet on your previous question - use say `D:(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GRGX;;;IU)` fror SD

Comment: @RbMm The security descriptor you mentioned only "locks" the edit to startup type option in the service properties; I require the service status section too to be locked (like in the screenshot above in the question). That's the reason I am reading the security descriptor of the services that already exibit this behavior as setting it to that of my service!

Comment: so set `D:(A;;GA;;;SY)` - in what problem ?!

Comment: or set `D:(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GR;;;IU)` - are you understand SDDL ?

Answer (score 0):

To set `OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION`, the calling process must have `WRITE_OWNER` access, or must be the owner of the object or have the `SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME` privilege enabled or `SE_RESTORE_NAME` when you set not self SID as the owner of object. And you don't need to set the SID of the owner of the object necessary.
The following sample work for me:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <WinError.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Fetch the security descriptor for "WdNisSvc" (Service name that corresponds to the display name of "Windows Security Service")

    LPCWSTR serviceNameToGetSecurityInformationFrom = L"SecurityHealthService";
    SC_HANDLE serviceManagerHandle = NULL, serviceHandle = NULL;
    char securityDescriptorBuffer[1024];
    DWORD lengthOfReturnedValue = 0;
    LPSTR daclBuffer = nullptr, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer = nullptr;
    DWORD daclBufferSize = NULL, ownerSidBufferSize = NULL, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize = NULL, saclBufferSize = NULL, primaryGroupSidBufferSize = NULL;
    WCHAR serviceName[] = L"MySampleService1";
    DWORD securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue = NULL;
    BOOL securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue = NULL;
    serviceManagerHandle = OpenSCManager(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (serviceManagerHandle == nullptr) {
        cout << "Error opening Service Manager Handle (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
    }
    else {
        serviceHandle = OpenService(serviceManagerHandle, serviceNameToGetSecurityInformationFrom, READ_CONTROL); //| WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC


        if (serviceHandle == nullptr) {
            cout << "Error opening service (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
        }
        else {
            if (!QueryServiceObjectSecurity(serviceHandle, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, securityDescriptorBuffer, sizeof(securityDescriptorBuffer), &lengthOfReturnedValue)) {
                cout << "Error obtaining service's security information (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
            }
            else {
                BOOL bDaclPresent = false, bDaclDefaulted = false;
                PACL pDacl = NULL;
                BOOL ret = GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(securityDescriptorBuffer, &bDaclPresent, &pDacl, &bDaclDefaulted);
                if (bDaclPresent)
                {
                    securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue = SetNamedSecurityInfo(serviceName, SE_SERVICE, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, pDacl, NULL);
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "The security descriptor doesn't contain a DACL" << endl;
                }
                //SC_HANDLE target_service = OpenService(serviceManagerHandle, serviceName, WRITE_DAC); //| WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC
                //if (serviceHandle == nullptr) {
                //    cout << "Error opening service (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
                //}
                //else {
                //    BOOL ret = SetServiceObjectSecurity(target_service, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, securityDescriptorBuffer);
                //    if (ret == 0) {
                //        cout << "Error SetServiceObjectSecurity (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
                //    }
                //    CloseServiceHandle(target_service);
                //}

            }
            CloseServiceHandle(serviceHandle);
        }
        CloseServiceHandle(serviceManagerHandle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or just use [`SetServiceObjectSecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-setserviceobjectsecurity):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <WinError.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Fetch the security descriptor for "WdNisSvc" (Service name that corresponds to the display name of "Windows Security Service")

    LPCWSTR serviceNameToGetSecurityInformationFrom = L"SecurityHealthService";
    SC_HANDLE serviceManagerHandle = NULL, serviceHandle = NULL;
    char securityDescriptorBuffer[1024];
    DWORD lengthOfReturnedValue = 0;
    LPSTR daclBuffer = nullptr, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer = nullptr;
    DWORD daclBufferSize = NULL, ownerSidBufferSize = NULL, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize = NULL, saclBufferSize = NULL, primaryGroupSidBufferSize = NULL;
    WCHAR serviceName[] = L"MySampleService1";
    DWORD securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue = NULL;
    BOOL securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue = NULL;
    serviceManagerHandle = OpenSCManager(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (serviceManagerHandle == nullptr) {
        cout << "Error opening Service Manager Handle (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
    }
    else {
        serviceHandle = OpenService(serviceManagerHandle, serviceNameToGetSecurityInformationFrom, READ_CONTROL); //| WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC


        if (serviceHandle == nullptr) {
            cout << "Error opening service (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
        }
        else {
            if (!QueryServiceObjectSecurity(serviceHandle, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, securityDescriptorBuffer, sizeof(securityDescriptorBuffer), &lengthOfReturnedValue)) {
                cout << "Error obtaining service's security information (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
            }
            else {
                //securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue = MakeAbsoluteSD(securityDescriptorBuffer, NULL, &absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize, (PACL)daclBuffer, &daclBufferSize, NULL, &saclBufferSize, NULL, &ownerSidBufferSize, NULL, &primaryGroupSidBufferSize);
                //if ((!securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue) && (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) == GetLastError()) {
                //    // Induced error
                //    //cout << "ERROR: Inadequate size of the buffers implemented.\n";
                //    absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer = new CHAR[absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize];
                //    daclBuffer = new CHAR[daclBufferSize];
                //    securityDescriptorInAbsoluteFormatCreationErrorValue = MakeAbsoluteSD(securityDescriptorBuffer, absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer, &absoluteSecurityDescriptionBufferSize, (PACL)daclBuffer, &daclBufferSize, NULL, &saclBufferSize, NULL, &ownerSidBufferSize, NULL, &primaryGroupSidBufferSize);
                //}
                //securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue = SetNamedSecurityInfo(serviceName, SE_SERVICE, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, (ACL*)daclBuffer, NULL);
                //if (securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                //    cout << "Error setting security info (" << securityInfoChangeOperationErrorValue << ").\n";
                //}
                //delete[] absoluteSecurityDescriptionBuffer;
                //delete[] daclBuffer;
                SC_HANDLE target_service = OpenService(serviceManagerHandle, serviceName, WRITE_DAC); //| WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC
                if (serviceHandle == nullptr) {
                    cout << "Error opening service (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
                }
                else {
                    BOOL ret = SetServiceObjectSecurity(target_service, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, securityDescriptorBuffer);
                    if (ret == 0) {
                        cout << "Error SetServiceObjectSecurity (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
                    }
                    CloseServiceHandle(target_service);
                }

            }
            CloseServiceHandle(serviceHandle);
        }
        CloseServiceHandle(serviceManagerHandle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Note:

> [`SetServiceObjectSecurity` is available for use in the operating
>   systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or
>   unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use the
>   `SetNamedSecurityInfo` function.]

Comment: To set `OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION` need also have `SeRestorePrivilege` when you set not self SID as the owner of object.

Comment: `MakeAbsoluteSD` - for what ? use `GetSecurityDescriptorDacl` on returned SD (need only if use `SetNamedSecurityInfo`)

Comment: about `SetServiceObjectSecurity` - it was, exist and will be. `SetNamedSecurityInfo` internal of course call `SetServiceObjectSecurity` and very not eficient compare `SetServiceObjectSecurity`.

Comment: and set `D:(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GR;;;IU)` if want disable change start type (write) and start/stop(execute) for service. if set `D:(A;;GA;;;SY)` it became at all invisible via services.msc

Answer (score 0):

`SecurityHealthService` is launched as protected as well as other importants services like `DoSvc` `WaaSMedicSvc` ..
(`SERVICE_LAUNCH_PROTECTED_WINDOWS_LIGHT`)

That's why you get `ACCESS_IS_DENIED` when calling `SetServiceObjectSecurity`.

*(`SetNamedSecurityInfo("..", SE_SERVICE..` will call  `SetServiceObjectSecurity`)*

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_launch_protected_info

> Once the service is launched as protected, other unprotected processes
> will not be able to call the following APIs on the protected service:
>
> - ChangeServiceConfig
> - ChangeServiceConfig2
> - ControlService
> - ControlServiceEx
> - DeleteService
> - SetServiceObjectSecurity

---

Further reading about protected services :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/protecting-anti-malware-services-

### Unregistering the service

When you uninstall a protected service, the
service must mark itself as unprotected by calling the
ChangeServiceConfig2 API. Note that because the system doesn't allow
any non-protected process to alter the configuration of a protected
service, the call to ChangeServiceConfig2 must be made by the
protected service itself. After the service has been reconfigured to
run as unprotected, the uninstaller can simply take appropriate steps
to remove the anti-malware software from the system.

---

The 3 solutions i'm aware of to be able to alter a protected service are :

- Using Group Policies (Security template)
- Creating a protected service to disable another protected service
- Running your programm under TrustedInstaller (Dirty ;))